# A project vanished from my local TFS workspace. It's added to source control but not checked in. Anywhere else to find it?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

This is a bit strange.

I created a project, added it to source control, worked on it for a day or two, but never checked it in.

Somehow, the project went missing from my local workspaces folder.  It's just gone.

In Source Control Explorer in VS.. it shows a green plus next to the project on both the TFS pane and the local pane.

[image]

If I right click the project in the local pane and choose Check In, it prepares my check-in, and when I finally proceed with the check-in process, I get this error:

```
C:\Users\<me>\Source\Workspaces\Workspace\AG\libCrypto\AGCrypto.sln: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\<me>\Source\Workspaces\Workspace\AG\libCrypto\AGCrypto.sln'.
```

Because, as I said.. the project folder vanished.  This is really concerning.. especially if it were to happen to a larger project.   Under no circumstance would I ever manually remove something from my workspace folder.

Could there possibly be anywhere else where I might be able to find my project?  Maybe in some cache/temp location?

I'm using VS 2015 Enterprise, TFS2015

Answer (score 0):

TFS won't remove project from workspace. I'm afraid you there is wrong process or operation on your local machine causes the project deleted.

As your project hasn't been checked into TFS, TFS doesn't have record for this project, it's unable to get your project back on TFS side.

You need to focus on how to recover files on your local machine if you need the project back.